# How to test if xml file is getting called or not?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am calling one xml file from another.

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
               <pp xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
                    <xx>aa</xx>
                 <yy>bb</yy>
                   <xi:include href="A.xml" parse="xml"/>
                 </person>
```

But I am not sure how to test this one , I mean if its really getting called/refereed or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make that xml file you are referring invalid, put an error in it and see if it shows up in the original document.

Comment: yeah..tried, but no error is showing.Do u see in problem in my code?

Comment: try adding parse="xml" and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just look at the output and see if the content from `A.xml` is actually there or not?